# Recommendation for references on cartography from the viewpoint of modern differential geometry

Tags: differential-geometry, reference-request, cartography

could someone recommend some references where the problem of constructing an accurate map of the Earth is tackled from the point of view of general maps between manifolds (so something like [this](http://virtualmath1.stanford.edu/%7Econrad/diffgeomPage/handouts/mapmaking.pdf) and not like [this](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1412.7690.pdf)) ?

Thanks!

Comment: How is this related to mathematics?

Comment: It's related since constructing a projection from the Earth (represented by a sphere or ellipsoid or some other smooth manifold) to a flat map is a differential geometry problem, where asking for certain desirable properties of the map (e.g. being angle-preserving for navigation) is translated to precise requirements on the induced metric tensor.  Please see the first link of the post.

Comment: Isn't your first link a reference for that? What do you not like about it?

Comment: It is indeed a nice resource, but it would be great if the reference included treatment of other aspects, e.g. Tissot's indicatrix as well as the relationship to the classical approach of constructing projections via developable surfaces. Also would be good to have something published so it's more permanent